# algorithm to find all values that occur more than n/10 times

Tags: algorithms, quicksort, java

I took an algorhytm course on coursera and there some **optional** questions for student enrichment. I can't solve the following task:

> **Decimal dominants.** Given an array with n keys, design an algorithm to find all values that occur more than n/10 times. The expected
>   running time of your algorithm should be linear.

And authors provied following hint:

> Hint: determine the (n/10)-th largest key using quickselect and check
>   if it occurs more than n/10 times.

Actually it is not cleat for me how can quick select help me. quick select is algorhitm which can help to find k-th largest element in linear time. In the lecture materials written that it work approximately linear.

Let's work with example. We have 100 elements array. We found 10-th elements.
( frankly speaking according the book we found such element order that all elements with index > 90 more **or equals** than elems[90] and all elements with index < 90 less **or equals** elem[90]

1. How can I calculate occurences?
2. Imagine, that we calculated occurences and it is less than 10. What would be the next step?

P.S.

[image: http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/12/02/0005/3037/338909/09/d99f2edb52.jpg]

Comment: The hint seems wrong. Can you double check?

Comment: @Apass.Jack, http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/12/02/0005/3037/338909/09/d99f2edb52.jpg

Comment: Finally I can see the hint make sense!

Comment: @Apass.Jack, could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I will. The basic idea is divide and conquer built on top of quickselect.

Comment: @Apass.Jack, I am sorry but it still unclrear for me.

Comment: @Apass.Jack 3-way quicksort ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the hint was aiming at the following approach. Suppose that the array were sorted. If a value appears $m$ times and we divide the array into intervals of length $m$, then the value must appear at the end of one of the intervals. This suggests the following algorithm for finding all values that appear $n/C$ times: compute the $i \cdot n/C$-largest elements for $1 \leq i \leq C$, and for each of them, check whether the value appears at least $n/C$ times. Each iteration takes $O(n)$ time using Quickselect, for a total of $O(Cn)$ time.